# How to hover over jQuery UI Tooltip without losing onHover menu below

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, hover, tooltip

I have a vertical menu that I am making and it is activated on hover. You hover over the menu item on the left and the mega menu shows up to the right. From there, I want to hover over those menu items and have jQuery IU Tooltip show the next level, like on [www.newegg.com](http://www.newegg.com) under all products.

What is happening is that when I hover over the jQuery UI Tooltip, the menu underneath disappears. How would I go about stopping that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be better off making your own javascript to handle this.
Use jquery's `$(element).hover()` and `$(element).mouseout()` to accomplish this.

When a user hovers over a menu item, you can give it some sort of selected class. Then you can have some css that gives `menu-item.selected > child-menu {display: block;}`.

When a user leaves the child, you can do a check for if they hovered into the parent menu-item, or vice versa. If that's true, remove the `selected` class from that  particular menu-item.

EDIT: make sure you give all the child-menu's an initial css of `display: none`